# Illustrator CS4: when I select an object with the Selection tool, and try and move it, it copies it instead

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mac, cs4

This is in a file originally created in version and installation of Illustrator CS4.

I have a simple text item with one character in it. Alternately, I pick a drawn element, doesn't matter.

I have the Selection Tool, i.e. the all black arrow. I'm not touching the keyboard. I click on the object (selected or unselected, doesn't matter), and drag, the cursor changes to the copy object version, and it copies the object. But I want to move it.

Illustrator knows properly what mode my keys are in, it does the right thing if I type in `option-e e` to get an é.

Comment: Odd. Now, this doesn't remove the actual problem, but what if you option-drag the layer? I mean, as this normally copies the dragged layer, could it revert your action to normal?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I tried getting into the layers panel, and option-dragging the layer callout there, and it simply didn't move, and nothing happened. When I simply dragged it, it pulled on outline which snapped back, since I have just one layer.

Comment: If I option-drag the object, it copies it, as you'd expect.

Comment: What OS (including exact version number if on Mac OS X)?

Comment: Hmmm, coulda sworn I mentioned this earlier. OSX 10.6.6

Answer (score 4):

After a visit to the Adobe forums and trawling around there for a while, I saw someone with the opposite problem who solved it by logging out. It was worth a shot, it's not something I do often.

This fixed it.

Thank you to everyone who offered me suggestions, I do appreciate the support.

Comment: +1 When in doubt, reboot. In fact, I reboot every Monday morning as a matter of course.

Comment: My brother the IT guy says if any problem can be solved by restarting, rebooting, or logging out and in again, you have to put a quarter in his Guru Jar. That usually takes out a third of the problems people would otherwise bring him.

Comment: As an longtime computer guy, I *hate* problems that are fixed by logging out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Some troubleshooting ideas:

- Does this happen in other files you
  created in this version and
  installation?
- Does this happen in files originated
  on someone else's machine?
- If you copy this file to someone
  else's machine, does it happen there?
- If you copy the contents of the file to a
  new file and save it under a new
  name, does it still happen? (don't just save-as. Select all, copy, new file, paste, save.)
- You said "option" so I'm guessing
  you're on a Mac. Did you check in
  System Preferences --> Universal
  Access to make sure you didn't turn
  on a helper key by accident? (I've
  done that with the zoom on occasion
  — scares the *crap* out of
  me when my text suddenly blows up to
  4000%.)
- In the same vein, are you clicking
  with the correct side of the mouse or
  the correct mouse button? (that is, you're not right-clicking when you mean to left-click, or holding down the right mouse button at the same time that you're dragging.)

Comment: Does it happen to other files: Yes

Comment: Universal access: Universally off

Comment: Right side stills shows a context menu, no nope, they aren't switched.

Comment: I can't test the other machine ideas, but I also don't know what that might tell us. I can say this: It's happening on files where it didn't before, so I don't think it's a per file thing.

Comment: Aaaaand getting rid of my preferences didn't help.

Comment: Other machines can confirm that the problem is on your machine, rather than part of your files. If you can, go more drastic: uninstall and reinstall Illustrator.